# Firefox addon: Convert asynchronous to synchronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firefox-addon, synchronous

I'm just curious if it is possible in Firefox addon to call a function that would wait to callback in asynchronous function call. It could be potentially useful.

For example

```
function async_func(callback) {
     ...
     callback(2);
}

function callback_foo(x) { return x*x; }
var results = Sync.wait_for_async_callback(async_func, callback_foo);
// now, results is 2*2 = 4
....
```

I know that javascript engine is generally one-thread so it's not allowed to run simultaneously synchronous waiting, sleeping in `Sync.wait_for_async_callback` and calling callback in `async_func` or functions called from `async_func`.

But I've found by chance [this article](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/JS_Modules#Sync) that may point that it would be possible. However I can't find needed module for this (a `Sync.js` file). [Link](http://hg.mozdev.org/jsmodules/file/tip/Sync.js) on that article doesn't seems to be useful (errors in server-side code?) Firefox code on [Mozilla-central](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/find?text=&string=Sync.js) doesn't know this file.

Maybe Web Workers or [nsIThreadManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIThreadManager) could be other way to convert async to sync call.

Comment: Why don’t you just use a callback?

Comment: @AdrianLang
I know callback generally would be good solution because doesn't froze a thread but for example callback can't be used when there is need for return value in function. Greater problem would be when something doesn't support async functions, only sync. 

For example the extension Bookmark Favicon Change is [broken](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=834457#c17) because it need rewrite internal Firefox function that is synchronous and Mozilla removed some sync functions. There is need return value that can't be returned in callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the [Sync.js module](https://www.epointsystem.org/trac/epoint_wallet/browser/trunk/firepay/resource/modules/Sync.js). It uses synchrounous waiting for next events by [processNextEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIThread#processNextEvent%28%29) until callback will be fired:

```
let thread = Cc["@mozilla.org/thread-manager;1"].getService().currentThread;
while (async callback not fired yet)
     thread.processNextEvent(true);
```

This trick seems to work but according to Marco Bonardo [it is bad choice](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=834457#c21) (crashes?)

Comment: some notes about using spinning event loop: from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Threads#Waiting_for_a_background_task_to_complete), by [Andrew Sutherland](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608095#c0)

Answer (score 0):

This is done with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm), read {this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm) which is based on [this specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises).

Comment: Thanks for the link. However it looks only like more convenient way using asynchronous code. There isn't magically calling async function using synchronous way. I can get result of asynchonous code only in callback definded in `promise.then` function.